# jQuery bind action on many events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very begginer question, but I can't find out the way I should execute a function on two different events: when the page is loaded AND when the checkbox is changed.

For now, here is what I have. It works but it's supid because not DRY:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    if ($("#visit_mode").prop('checked')){
      $("#cart_div").hide();
      $("#visit_div").show();
    }
    if ($("#cart_mode").prop('checked')){
      $("#visit_div").hide();
      $("#cart_div").show();
    }

  });

$(".checkbox").change(function() {

  if ($("#visit_mode").prop('checked')){
    $("#cart_div").hide();
    $("#visit_div").show();
  }
  if ($("#cart_mode").prop('checked')){
    $("#visit_div").hide();
    $("#cart_div").show();
  }

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign that code to a *named* function

```
$(document).ready(namedFunction);

$(".checkbox").change(namedFunction);

function namedFunction(){
  if ($("#visit_mode").prop('checked')){
    $("#cart_div").hide();
    $("#visit_div").show();
  }
  if ($("#cart_mode").prop('checked')){
    $("#visit_div").hide();
    $("#cart_div").show();
  }

}
```

Comment: Should I understand, Sir, that this is just a more elegant/lightweight solution, and that internal behaviour is the same between OP and answer? I am a beginner trying to understand more

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers, the overall behavior is the same. What has changed matters more semantically rather than internally. Internally, essentially the same code is executed. Semantically, we grouped the similar code into one place

Comment: @AmmarCSE, thank you for all the knowlegde you share as usual